# Find 'text' in Span and enter in input and click button.... jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

In Wordpress I have a 'single' template for a certain post type. One of the metas displayed on the page is an address which is displayed in a span.

Additionally I have a FacetWP template which returns other posts. There is a single 'facet' for location.

I need to take the address from the span and enter it into the input and effectively hit 'return' on the input. This will trigger a refresh of the results which will now be sorted according to their proximity to the address entered in the location input.

So the markup abstract is in effect this..

```
<span>1 main street, london, uk</span>
<input type="text" class="facetwp-location" value="" placeholder="Enter location" autocomplete="off" id="facetwp-location">
```

Does anyone know how I might achieve this?

UPDATE:

This is the FULL markup associated with the input. Ordinarilya user would begin typing in the area and a google list of addresses would appear. The user would select one and the facets would be triggered upon making that selection. Alternatively an address could be fully entered manually and the user may hit enter.

```
<div class="facetwp-facet facetwp-facet-location facetwp-type-proximity" data-name="location" data-type="proximity">        <span class="location-wrap"><i class="locate-me"></i><input type="text" class="facetwp-location" value="" placeholder="Enter location" autocomplete="off" id="facetwp-location"><div class="location-results facetwp-hidden"></div></span>

        
        <input class="facetwp-radius facetwp-hidden" value="250" id="facetwp-radius">

        
        <input type="hidden" class="facetwp-lat" value="">
        <input type="hidden" class="facetwp-lng" value="">
</div>
```

Screenshot of page's markup;

[image]

Comment: Is the `input` surrounded by a `form` tag or is it submitted by pressing the return key only (through a JavaScript event handler)?

Comment: Question edited by way of a response @Narigo

Comment: Since there are hidden input fields, I suppose there is a `form` tag higher up the tree somewhere?

Comment: Screenshot added.... No form tag as far as I can determine.. @Narigo

Comment: Maybe I should add that FacetWP is an ajax powered filtering plugin for Wordpress so the area where the results of the queries are shown is refreshed via ajax and as such no forms are submitted and there is no page reload.

Comment: The reason I was asking is that you could try to get the form of the input tag and call its `submit` function through JavaScript. You might achieve the same by triggering a keypress event for the return, but that would feel very hacky. I guess FacetWP can be called with [their JavaScript API](https://facetwp.com/documentation/developers/javascript/js-objects/) instead

Comment: Well I guess the first step it to get that input populated with the address from the <span>....don't you think?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217709/discussion-between-narigo-and-briany-hearne).